# 'No overloaded version' error when replacing string in a stringlist

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to replace a char in a TStringList, But the compiler gives me a 'No overloaded version' error. This is my code.

```
procedure TForm1.bImportCSVClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  aCSVFile : TStringList;
  aCSVLine : TStringList;
  aString : string;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.execute then
  begin
    aCSVFile := TStringList.Create;
    aCSVLine := TStringList.Create;
    try
      aCSVFile.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);

      aCSVFile := StringReplace(aCSVFile, ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]); //Error

      aCSVLine.Delimiter := ';';
      for aString in aCSVFile do
      begin
        aCSVLine.DelimitedText := aString;
        ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([aCSVLine[0]]);
      end;
    finally
      aCSVFile.Free;
      aCSVLine.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

I have tried the following:

```
      for aString in aCSVFile do
      begin
        aCSVLine.DelimitedText := aString;
        aCSVLine[0] := StringReplace(aCSVLine[0], ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
        ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([aCSVLine[0]]);
      end;
```

Comment: String list is a list of strings. You need to choose a string from the list to change its char. Which string from your list do you want to manipulate with ?

Comment: its the first string of every line

Comment: The compiler message means exactly what it says. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first parameter of `StringReplace` is of type `string`. You pass `TStringList`.
- The return value of `StringReplace` is of type `string`. You assign to `TStringList`.

You need to operate on individual strings rather than the entire list. For instance, if you want to operate on every item in the list you would write:

```
for i := 0 to aCSVFile.Count-1 do
  aCSVFile[i] := StringReplace(aCSVFile[i], ' ', '', [rfReplaceAll]);
```

As to what is the correct code for you, I have no idea because you did not specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: This exactly. Just replace ' ' with '' (I need to remove spaces from poscodes) Thank you verry much